# Fixed UIView at bottom of the screen ignores NSLayoutConstraint changes

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm experiencing this strange behavior inside my auto-layouted view using Xcode5.

I have a `UIView` fixed to the bottom of the screen and upon tap of a button, I'm updating the bottom:0 constraint to bottom:-60 which effectively moves it off the visible screen. This animation works fine as long as this UIView does not have any subviews.

Now, I added two `UIButtons` inside this UIView and the animation triggered by setting

```
[self.bottomConstraint setConstant:-60];
```

is simply ignored. The view and its two `UIButton` subviews remain visible as if `self.bottomConstraint.constant` was still `0`.

I thought it may have to do with `translatedAutoresizingMasksToConstraints` so I set that to `NO`. Without success... Ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this method on your main view (the superview of the first UIView you reference in your question) after you change the constraint's constant:

```
[mainView setNeedsLayout];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to animate the layout changes once you updated the constraints, you need to call layoutIfNeeded in an animation block.

It would look something like this:

```
[self.bottomConstraint setConstant:-60];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [view layoutIfNeeded]; // view is the UIView that contains your button
}];
```

`layoutIfNeeded` layouts the subviews in the view hierarchy starting with the one you call the method on immediately. `setNeedsLayout` just marks the view to have it's layout refreshed at the next layouting cycle.